# Hive - multiple (average) count distincts over layered groups

Tags: sql, hive, group-by, hiveql

Given the following source data (say the table name is `user_activity`):

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| user_id | user_type | some_date  |
+---------+-----------+------------+
| 1       | a         | 2018-01-01 |
| 1       | a         | 2018-01-02 |
| 2       | a         | 2018-01-01 |
| 3       | a         | 2018-01-01 |
| 4       | b         | 2018-01-01 |
| 4       | b         | 2018-01-02 |
| 5       | b         | 2018-01-02 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I'd like to get the following result:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| user_type | user_count | average_daily_users |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| a         | 3          | 2                   |
| b         | 2          | 1.5                 |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

using a single query without multiple subqueries on the same table.

---

Using multiple queries, I can get:

- `user_count`:

  ```
  select
    user_type,
    count(distinct user_id)
  from user_activity
  group by user_type
  ```
- For `average_daily_users`:

  ```
  select
    user_type,
    avg(distinct_users) as average_daily_users
  from (
    select
      count(distinct user_id) as distinct_users
    from user_activity
    group by user_type, some_date
  )
  group by user_type
  ```

But I can't seem to write a query that does what I want in one go. I am concerned about the performance impact of multiple subqueries on the same table (it will have to scan through the table twice... right?) I have a rather large data source and would like to minimize running time.

NOTE: *The question is titled Hive because that is what I'm working with, but I think it is a generic enough SQL problem so I'm not ruling out answers in other languages.*

NOTE2: *This question shares details with [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956608/hive-over-partition-by-with-a-column-not-in-group-by) on `partition by` columns in window functions (for computing the average daily users column).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
select ua.user_type,
       count(distinct ua.user_id) as user_count,
       count(distinct some_date || ':' || ua.user_id) / count(distinct some_date)
from user_activity ua
group by ua.user_type;
```

Comment: Good idea! I didn't even consider doing the average myself. It feels so wrong, yet so right. TYVM!